# Unable connect to remote git from Visual Studio

Tags: git, bash, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gitlab

I'm not able connect to remote git repository (running with gitlab) from Visual Studio as well from Power shell however from git-bash.vbs (visal basic script from Git directory in Program Files - it seems like it add arguments "--login -i") it works with error message: "fatal: unable to access 'https://path-to.com/git-project.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to path-to.com:443". How can I specify in Visual Studia those arguments for git or how can I specify where to find "id_rsa.pub" file to use in VS?
As SSH I'm running with OpenSSH for windows and as a git client is Git for Windows v1.9.5 (installed from chocolatey).

Comment: How did you install the Visual Studio extension, did you do it from within Visual Studio? If so, try removing it and installing it by downloading the .vsix file and using that. There was a bug in how the extension was installed earlier, it may be that you have some remnants of that left.

Comment: Thank to replay - it's my first shot with git, I didn't know that I need to install SSH, so at first I installed Git from Visual Studio, then removed it and install GitHub for Windows, than install Git from chocolatey and than install OpenSSH (it removed all paths from system PATH, awesome...) but Ok I'll try to reinstall again :)